# Android Apache POI

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, powerpoint

Hello i am using Apache POI to get slides from pptx like quickoffice android but i got an error code is:

```
XMLSlideShow ppt;
XSLFSlide blankSlide;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ppt/test.pptx"));

        //append a new slide to the end
        blankSlide = ppt.createSlide();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

After the compilation i got an error and application stopped
error:

```
02-08 16:07:25.010  31587-31587/ D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-08 16:07:25.010  31587-31587/ W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162ed40)
02-08 16:07:25.011  31587-31587/ E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: PID: 31587
java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow
at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note: I am using android studio and using ApachePOI 3.11 jars
Thanks in Advance

Comment: hi. this link maybe helps you to understand the cause of this error: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-verifyerror-how-to-solve-verifyerror/